# root.findall() not returning anything

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree, findall

I'm trying to get the values stored in the ActiveOffer tags in the XML below but it seems as though the condition to satisfy the for loop is not being met but I don't know why:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Config File="Rating/saved/DataPostpaid.cfg" Origin="Member1">
    <ServiceProvider Name="Rating">
        <RatingPlan Name="1" Service="Rating">
            <RatingPeriod Name="DataPostpaid">
                <TariffStructure>
                    <Node id="defs" type="Defs">
                    Definitions
                        <Condition id="Local">
                            ActiveOffer
                            <ActiveOffer>15</ActiveOffer>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition id="Roaming">
                            ActiveOffer
                            <ActiveOffer>216</ActiveOffer>
                        </Condition>
                        <Condition id="Premium SCs">
                            ServiceClass
                            <Comment>Premium</Comment>
                            <Values>6-10
                            13
                            22-40</Values>
                        </Condition>
                    </Node>
                </TariffStructure>
            </RatingPeriod>
        </RatingPlan>
    </ServiceProvider>
</Config>
```

I put print("yes") immediately within the for loop but nothing prints... any assistance will be appreciated.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for x in root.findall('Condition'):
    offer = x.find('ActiveOffer').text
    print(offer)
```

Comment: I believe `findall()` only finds _direct_ children.  Your `<Condition>` tags are nested many levels deep, and are not direct children.

Comment: Use `root.findall('.//Condition')` to find `Condition` elements on any level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findall()` together with an XPATH to achieve your goal:

```
for x in root.findall('.//ActiveOffer'):
    ...
```

This searches the XML tree recursively and returns all `ActiveOffer` elements. If you want to restrict the search to `ActiveOffer` elements that are inside `Condition` elements, use this:

```
for x in root.findall('.//Condition/ActiveOffer'):
    ...
```

The `.//` bit of the XPATH tells `findall()` to search recursively, starting from the current element. You can read more about XPATH support [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath).

**Why your example didn't work**

`findall('Contidion')` performs a non-recursive search. You called `findall()` on the `root` element (`Config`), so the only thing it can find is its child element `ServiceProvider`:

```
>>> root
<Element 'Config' at 0x02398F60>
>>> root.findall('*')
[<Element 'ServiceProvider' at 0x025422D0>]
```